# Allowing a specific IP Address through a blocked port in Windows Server 2008 R2 Firewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, ip, port

I have created an Inbound rule to block port number 1433 however I need to allow my static ip address to access this as I use SQL Management Studio to connect to databases on the server.

I have tried adding my ip address to the "Scope - Remote IP addresses" but it does not seem to work. Am I missing something here, maybe I need to add some sort of rule for SQL Management Studio on the server, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's firewall have some sort of "automatic rules order management": most specific rules have priority.
In other words, if you have a "general" blocking rule and a "specific" allowing rule, then your allowing rule have better priority, so the paquets pass.

So just add a rule to allow your computer to reach the server.